# Are facial muscles activated in verbal thought?

Tags: neuroscience, memory, motor

In [this video](https://youtu.be/sPFmKu2S5XY?t=13m49s), Dr Russel Barkley states the following:

> I can put electrodes all over your face and I can ask you to cite your
>   Canadian pledge of allegiance in your mind. You still move your face.
>   The muscle movements are so small that they're inperciptible to you
>   and to others. But they're measurable. The human face is moving any
>   time you engage in verbal thought. So is your larynx, by the way.

I am having a hard time locating a source for this though, and have never heard of it. Does anyone know if this is true?